# Using `ldconfig` while not touching system files

Tags: linker

I have compiled a library and now I should run `ldconfig`.  However, I would rather not modify `/etc/ld.so.conf`, nor any other system file.  Is it possible to generate the cache somewhere else and then make it visible only while compiling selected programs?  Or should I manually set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for option `-f` of [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig):

> **-f conf**
>       Use conf instead of /etc/ld.so.conf.

If you run:

```
ldconfig -f custom.conf
```

with user with enough privileges it will modify `/etc/ld.so.cache`. `ld` reads `/etc/ld.so.cache` and I don't think you can make it to read from different file.

As you don't want to modify system files you can do following:

```
gcc -W -Wall -L/path_to_your_library -lyour_library test.c -o testo
```

to build your testo.c

Then:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_your_library
```

to run it although  setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` help with debugging and to try out a newer version of a library its usage in the general development environment setup and deployment is considered bad. More you can check [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Another approach could be using `rpath`:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -L/path_to_your_library -Wl,-rpath=/path_to_your_library -W -Wall -o testo testo.c -lyour_library
```

With `rpath` method each program  gets to list its shared library locations independently. Downsides: shared libraries should be installed in a fixed location. Also I've not tested but may be issues if library refers to a NFS mount.

Comment: Thanks.  But then, how will I make that cache visible to `ld`?  With the `@file` option of `ld`, maybe?

Comment: If you run `ldconfig -f custom.conf` as root it will modify `/etc/ld.so.cache` and it should be visisble. `ld` reads `ld.so.cache` and I don't think you can make it to read from different file, though with option `-C` of `ldconfig` you can create different cache file.

Comment: But that would be exactly what I am trying to avoid: changing system files.  Maybe I could set the `-L` and `-l` options of GCC, instead, basically doing by hand what `ld` does?

Comment: @Elena, answer edited.